# Having Google Chrome td make new line on printed pages

Tags: javascript, html, css

in my web site when i press result button the table of results show in correct format such first image 
but when i click print button table formate is damged 
there is 2 images clarify the issue

```
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <tr class="print-header">
                <th class="table-head" ng-repeat="cols in headercolumns">{{cols}}</th>
            </tr>

            <tr class="table-row" ng-repeat="scoresheet in scoresheets |filter:class">
                <td>
                    <p style="font-size : 20px">{{scoresheet.user.name}}</p>
                    <span>{{scoresheet.user.class.name}}</span>
                </td>
                <td><p style="font-size : 20px">{{scoresheet.result.statistics.score |number}}</p></td>
                <td><p style="font-size : 20px">{{scoresheet.result.statistics.correct_answers}}</p></td>
                <td><p style="font-size : 20px">{{scoresheet.result.statistics.incorrect_answers}}</p></td>
                <td><p style="font-size : 20px">{{scoresheet.result.statistics.partial_answers}}</p></td>
                <td><p style="font-size : 20px">{{scoresheet.result.statistics.pending_answers}}</p></td>
                <td><p style="font-size : 20px">{{scoresheet.result.statistics.skipped_answers}}</p></td>
              </tr>
```

[result table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7g8P.png)
[printing table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCWBy.png)

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: State your question first

Comment: Where is the second image and what do you want us to do and where is td line occurring automatically

Comment: @adityashrivastava There are two inline image links; OP didn't format correctly. First is "my layout" second is "epriting layout".

Comment: Just wondering: Is this Bootstrap/some other layout system? If so, it may have some built-in print layouts that you're going to have to overwrite.

Comment: @TheValyreanGroup haider_kazal sorry i updated the question

Comment: @aditya shrivastava result table  printing table this is the 2 imges

Comment: @Quangdao Nguyen thanks alot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solve my issue.

```
@media print {
    td {
        display: table-cell !important; 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use media queries to style print documents. In your CSS you can do something like:

```
@media print {
    td {
        display: block;
    }    
}
```

Otherwise, I believe you can also import a separate stylesheet in your HTML, though I've never done this myself:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/path/to/print.css" media="print">
```

[Read More](http://www.joshuawinn.com/css-print-media-query/)

[JSFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/TheQueue841/jxpjnaaw/)

Comment: thank you very much @Quangdao Nguyen
but I already have done this but the issue still exist

Comment: Can you please clarify? The example seems to behave as expected, so I'm not sure what your issue is.

Comment: Did you see the 2 images ?
that is what exactly happen

Comment: in my web site when press result button show the table of result in correct format when i press print button the format is damaged @Quangdao Nguyen

Comment: So are you trying to _avoid_ the second image? Sorry, it seemed like that's what you were trying to achieve. I suggest editing your question to make that clearer. But I'm not sure why it would do that; have you tried isolating that section to see how it appears?